# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Nested for loop?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I don't know why I got an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` inside the nested for loop... It only prints the first inner for loops and never proceed to the outer for loop.
Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
public static double weight(){
    //int counter = 0;
    System.out.println("####" + d);
    while(Math.abs(delta_w) > 0.001){
        for(int i = 0; i < 33; i++ ){

            for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++ ){

                if(Math.abs(delta_w)!=0){

                    value = d.exData[i][j];    //?

                    y = d.exLabels[i];

                    percep = w * d.exData[i][j];
                    System.out.println(d.exData[i][j]);
                    delta_w = y - percep;

                    w+= delta_w;
//                  counter++;
                    System.out.println("value w " + w);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return w;
}
```

Comment: What is the size of your array?

Comment: what are the contents and sizes of your `exData` and `exLabels` arrays? are they within the limits of the values reached by `i` and `j`. Please specify the line at which you get the exception.

Comment: The full error message should tell you the line and index that is causing a problem. This, in combination with the size of the array, should tell you exactly why you're getting an exception, and probably also how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is 'd.exData.length == 1'

Why are you assuming the array size of 33 and 13? Why not use the count of the array instead?

```
public static double weight(){
    //int counter = 0;
    System.out.println("####" + d);
    while(Math.abs(delta_w) > 0.001){
        for(int i = 0; i < d.exData.length; i++ ){

            for(int j = 0; j < d.exData[i].length; j++ ){

                if(Math.abs(delta_w)!=0){

                    value = d.exData[i][j];    //?

                    y = d.exLabels[i];

                    percep = w * d.exData[i][j];
                    System.out.println(d.exData[i][j]);
                    delta_w = y - percep;

                    w+= delta_w;
                    //counter++;
                    System.out.println("value w " + w);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return w;
}
```